# How to track events before page redirect with google analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I use GA's trackEvent to record user's click event on search autocomplete of my site.
When user click on item of autocomplete, I record two event, and then page redirect to the result page.
But the problem is: the amount of the two action "click" and "view" is not equal, the amount of "click" > the amount of "view". 
I see the two request are sent in firebug, but they are both canceled because the page redirect. Even though they are canceled, I can see the result in GA.I just can't understand why they are not equal? The later one failed sometimes?

Here is the code part:

```
//trackEvent just use _gaq.push("trackEvent", xxx)
trackEvent("search", "click");
trackEvent("search", "view");
window.location.href = des;
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's the answer to your question:

[Google Analytics - Setting the Hit Callback](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits#hitcallback)